# how do you keep a console open after a runas command completes?

Tags: windows, console, runas

I'm trying to run the SharePoint 'stsadm' command using 'runas /user:spsetup "stsadm args...".  The user authenticates, and the program runs, but it runs in a new console window which closes immediately upon termination of the 'stsadm' program.  What can I do to keep it open?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`runas /user:spsetup "cmd /k echo Hello!"`

Answer (score 0):

Open a console window first and type the command there. The console will stay open even after the program has finished.